# Why will the icon on the card not increase in size when the px is increased

Tags: html, css

When I increase the px of the icon located on the cards (The Gaming Controller and the Question Mark) It will not change the actual size of the icon when I run the code, Is there  any other way to increase the size of these icons or a solution to my problem in anyway? Thanks for the help guys!

Here is my code :)

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.shell {
  height:65vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: center; /* Added */
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card-header {
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #D32F2F;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.main-description {
  color: #D32F2F;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #dfd5d7;
  color: #942626;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #D32F2F;
  color: #FFEBEE;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
</style>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <link rel="icon" type="png" href="/images/icon.png"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Project-LuLo</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="header">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">Project-LuLo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#games">Games</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="shell"> 
  <a href = "#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Games</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">videogame_asset</i>
      <div class="main-description">Web Based Games</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Other</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">question_mark</i>
      <div class="main-description">Cool Random Stuff</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `<i>` is an inline element, explicit widths and heights will not work on them. On the `.material-icons` selector add `display: inline-block`.

Comment: This did not work

Comment: How are you trying to increase the size of `.material-icon`?

Comment: @Project LuLo: you're loading the material icons css after your inlined `<style>` - thus,  **the original (external) css overrides your custom rules**. So skip the order (and revise your html structure ... there are a lot of wrong nestings). Use devtools to inspect elements: you will see, if any styles are overriden by more specific rules or contain invalid property values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to fix are adding "!important" to font-size it will work change your icon size, for example:

```
.material-icons {
  font-size: 30px!important;
  color: #D32F2F;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of why important is needed?